# Biometric USB Flash Drive with 10+ Stored Fingerprints

Tags: security, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, biometrics

I'm looking for a biometric (means it reads fingerprints) USB flash drive that allows 10+ users' to access with their fingerprints.

I need this to store sensitive data to which our support team is allowed to access. This will prevent us from storing passwords on any local machine and allow us to store passwords in a file that only those that are authorized can access.

Comment: Please consider using PKCS11 smart cards instead of passwords - a biometric but unencrypted USB drive, like just about every one on the market, is no more secure than a password file.

Comment: @Borealid is right... A heavily encrypted password file is probably even more secure than an unencrypted USB drive with fingerprint technology...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first find was : [XMicro Biometric USB Fingerprint Flash Drive 1GB](http://www.xmicro.com/xmicro_biometric_usb_fingerprint_flash_drive_1gb.htm), although it supports only up to 10 fingerprint templates.

Going further, I found that a simple query on [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=USB+fingerprint+reader&x=0&y=0&ih=1_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_0_1.534_56&fsc=-1) will give a list of 15 USB fingerprint readers, which will take too much space to reproduce here (although not all are Flash and not all of them fulfill all the requirements).

For the fun of it, here is from the above list the [Victorinox Secure 16GB USB Fingerprint](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003NSGN2A), which probably does more functions than you imagined :

[image]

Comment: who needs biometrics when you have a knife!

Comment: yea, the knife seems to be exactly the missing piece from the horror story about biometrics and cut fingers :D